# Different parameters, exactly same AUC

Tags: r, roc, auc

I have a dataset with two columns y and x.

I performed different algorithms to predict `y` based on `x`.

For each algorithm, I have a vector of predicting values: `p1`, `p2`.

I used the function `auc` of the package `pROC`.

```
auc (response = test$x, predictor = p1)
auc (response = test$x, predictor = p2)
```

I have exactly same AUC values at 6 decimals. Is it possible, or something is wrong with my implementation?

**Update:** `p1` and `p2` are different.

```
> pROC::auc (response = test$correct_value, predictor = p1)
Area under the curve: 0.8231
> pROC::auc (response = test$correct_value, predictor = p2)
Area under the curve: 0.8231
> head (p1)
        11         14         17         22         25         26 
0.01378549 0.01378549 0.01378549 0.01203714 0.01259412 0.01259412 
> head (p2)
       11        14        17        22        25        26 
0.7511921 0.7511921 0.7511921 0.6272434 0.6715637 0.6715637
```

Comment: Are `p1` and `p2` the same? Different "algorithms" can produce identical predictions.

Comment: No, they are different. I checked that.

Comment: I see, that you have discrete predictions (a limited number of values). As long as the order of these is the same, the AUC's will be the same. In your example output the orders are, for example, the same. AUC measures how often the p-value of an observation with the event (x=1) is larger than the p-value of an observation without the event (x=0); for all possible pairs. It only cares about the order, not the values.

Comment: To make sure that `auc` functions correctly, you could also try `Hmisc::somers2`

Comment: To test the ranks: `all(rank(p1) == rank(p2)`. If they are the same that does explain why the auc's are the same; doesn't explain why the predicted values are so different. Which still might be caused by an error.

Comment: Yes, the ranks are the same. In fact here ``p1`` and ``p2`` comes from the same algorithm (``glm``) but ``p2`` are trained by using SMOTE on the train dataset.

Answer (score 1):

@Jan van der Laan noted indeed that `all(rank(p1) == rank(p2))`. But there is more to it!

If I understand your question correctly, you make predictions with a `glm` model based on a single random variable `x`. Then the following is true too:

```
> pROC::auc (response = test$correct_value, predictor = x)
Area under the curve: 0.8231
> all(rank(p1) == rank(x))
[1] TRUE
```

The reason for this is that a linear function of a single random variable `x` *cannot possibly reorder the data*. As rank is the only relevant information for the ROC analysis, if you want to improve your predictions, you must either pass the data through a non-linear function (`nlm` or similar), or introduce more random variables in the equation.